# Bidirectional two networks link

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I have a two networks that I need to link in two directions.

- network A 10.11.0.0/24 - and its gateway 10.11.0.1
- network B 10.0.0.0/24

network B has a VPN server (10.0.0.38) that is doing a masquerade already, so network A can ping network B.

But the vice-versa isn't true, I can't make network B machines ping or see network A.

I tried to add this to a network B machine without a result:

```
route add  -net 10.11.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.38
```

How can I make network B see network A?

Edit#1 : OpenVPN, TUN mode.
I need to add routing on network A so it use the VPN server as its gateway to network B.

Comment: What VPN server? What mode is it set to?

Comment: What you really need is a router between a and b.  Or turn off the masquerading and use route statements on both sides.

Comment: Ron : Can you please give example of route statments ?? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I made a small [draw](http://s13.postimg.org/jusrkugjb/stack.png) because I think I misunderstand your problem. But as I understand it correctly (expect the VPN server thing) you should add the GW to the other interface too. What does it print out after invoking `route add  -net 10.11.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.38` ?

Comment: @csikos.balint Thanks for being interested, it prints nothing (no error message, and the routing becomes listed when I list the routes

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I just needed to make the command like this (adding the interface at the end) :

```
    route add  -net 10.11.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 10.0.0.38 eth0
```